# Fastest way to insert rows without violating the primary key

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a couple of tables with primary key constraints that i populate from c#.

**What would be the fastest way to insert rows without violating the primary key?**

Does executing statements one by one vs batch add a significant overhead?

If I would need to update certain rows based on conditions, would i be better off using a stored procedure and calling it point by point or use merge?

1.

```
foreach(var point in points)
{
    ...
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(@"
    BEGIN TRY 
        INSERT INTO POINTS ... 
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627 
        BEGIN 
            THROW 
        END
    END CATCH", con)
}
```

2.

```
foreach(var point in points)
{
    ...
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(@"
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from POINTS where ...) 
    INSERT INTO POINTS ...", con)
}
```

3.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("BEGIN TRAN");
foreach(var point in points)
{
    sb.AppendLine("IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from POINTS where ...) INSERT INTO POINTS ...")
}
sb.AppendLine("COMMIT TRAN");
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(sb.ToString());
```

4.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(@"
    BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @POINTS TABLE (
    ...
    )
");
foreach(var point in points)
{
    sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO @POINTS ...")
}
sb.AppendLine(@"
    MERGE POINTS as T
    USING @POINTS as S
    ON T.KEY=S.KEY
    WHEN OT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ...
");
sb.AppendLine("COMMIT TRAN");
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your points collection is large, consider using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to insert it into a temp table (e.g. `#NEW_POINTS`) first. That way you'll avoid running an individual INSERT statement per point.

Then, run a single MERGE or a combination of INSERT/UPDATE to move the data into your actual POINTS table.

Comment: This is the most efficient way. Just blast it into a holding table in the database, then you can use all the SQL set-based commands to massage the data into your live tables.

Comment: So the merge between the #NEW_POINTS and the POINTS table would perform better than with the @POINTS variable? I was thinking that because the merge is the one filtering out rows the performance of the insert inside the temp one is negligible

Comment: I would expect the MERGE to perform the same no matter whether using a temp table #POINTS or a variable @POINTS. However, using SqlBulkCopy will almost certainly be faster than INSERTing the points individually (foreach(var point in points) ... ).